# WHERE clause to get events which (could) span into a new day

Tags: mysql, date

I have data which represents an event. The important columns are

```
StartDate (date)
StartTime (time)
EndDate (date)
EndTime (time)
```

My where clause is

```
WHERE HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 14 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 14 
AND DATE(NOW()) >= L.StartDate AND DATE(NOW()) <= L.EndDate 
AND L.StartDate <= '2015-01-22' AND L.EndDate >= '2015-01-22'
```

Which will return me any events which started before or at 2pm AND which end at 3pm or later. The StartDate and EndDate is the range of this event, for example an event might occur every day in the month of January, or longer.

Now the issue is what if one of the events has data like this:

```
StartDate    |    StartTime    |    EndDate    |    EndTime
2015-01-01   |    14:00:00     |    2015-12-31 |    01:00:00
```

Meaning the event goes from 2pm-1am the next day. My query will not return the row because of the

```
AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 14
```

clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why not an or? Original search, OR stated possibility:

```
WHERE (HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 14 AND HOUR(L.EndTime) > 14 
AND DATE(NOW()) >= L.StartDate AND DATE(NOW()) <= L.EndDate 
AND L.StartDate <= '2015-01-22' AND L.EndDate >= '2015-01-22')
OR (HOUR(L.StartTime) <= 14
AND DATE(NOW()) >= L.StartDate AND DATE(NOW()) <= L.EndDate
AND L.StartDate <= '2015-01-22' AND L.EndDate >= '2015-01-22'
AND L.StartDate != L.EndDate)
```